# Ajuda com centralização de itens de uma grid

Tags: css, grid

Nao consigo centralizar verticalmente os itens da minha grid no meio da div #grid-container.
O engraçado que o justify-items:center; 
funciona ! 
porem align-items:center;
Não =(

```css
#grid-container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin:auto;


}
#grid{
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
                <ul>
                    <div id="grid-container">
                        <div id="grid">
                            <li id="">
                                <p><label for="submitreservation">Name</label></p>
                                <p><input class="inputnames" required type="text" name="name"
                                        placeholder="name example">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p><label for="submitreservation">Last Name</label></p>
                                <p><input class="inputnames" required type="text" name="lastname"
                                        placeholder="name example">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p><label for="email">E-mail :</label> </p>
                                <p><input required class="inputnames" type="email" name="email"
                                        placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p><label for="cellphone">Phone Number</label></p>
                                <p><input type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="[0-9]{11}"
                                        placeholder="Ex:13991234567">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    <label for="numpeople">Number of people</label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input required id="guests" type="number" name="numpeople" value="1" min="1"
                                        max="30">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p><label for="datereservation">Date of reservation</label></p>
                                <p><input required type="date" name="datereservation"></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p> <label for="timereservation">Hour</label></p>
                                <p><input id="hourinput" required type="time" name="timereservation"></p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p><input id="submitinput" required type="submit" name="submitreservation"
                                        value="Submit">
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: Vc quer o formulário no centro da página é isso?

Comment: da div no caso, sim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas já que vc está usando Grid sugiro vc a usar um `display: grid;` e `align-content: center;` na div pai `#grid-container` e também colocar uma altura no `form` e `ul`, pois o filho sempre pega a altura do pai, e o pai da `#grid-container` é a `ul` e o avó o `form`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como fica, **Execute em Página toda**, pois vc ainda não fez o tratamento responsivo acredito...

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form, ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#grid-container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin:auto;

    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
}
#grid{
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <div id="grid-container">
            <div id="grid">
                <li id="">
                    <p><label for="submitreservation">Name</label></p>
                    <p><input class="inputnames" required type="text" name="name"
                            placeholder="name example">
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p><label for="submitreservation">Last Name</label></p>
                    <p><input class="inputnames" required type="text" name="lastname"
                            placeholder="name example">
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p><label for="email">E-mail :</label> </p>
                    <p><input required class="inputnames" type="email" name="email"
                            placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p><label for="cellphone">Phone Number</label></p>
                    <p><input type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="[0-9]{11}"
                            placeholder="Ex:13991234567">
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>
                        <label for="numpeople">Number of people</label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input required id="guests" type="number" name="numpeople" value="1" min="1"
                            max="30">
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p><label for="datereservation">Date of reservation</label></p>
                    <p><input required type="date" name="datereservation"></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p> <label for="timereservation">Hour</label></p>
                    <p><input id="hourinput" required type="time" name="timereservation"></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p><input id="submitinput" required type="submit" name="submitreservation"
                            value="Submit">
                    </p>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</form>
```